# Polymer iron-form, submitted twice on enter

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, polymer

Working on a comment element in Polymer, where the comment should be submitted when the user presses enter. The enter part works, but the comment is getting submitted twice, causing a duplicate. Can you tell whats wrong? Thanks!

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/iron-form/iron-form.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/iron-input/iron-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/iron-a11y-keys/iron-a11y-keys.html">
<dom-module is="post-comments">
    <template>

        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="comment-input-wrapper">

                <iron-a11y-keys id="a11y" keys="enter" target="[[target]]"
                                on-keys-pressed="sendComment" stopKeyboardEventPropagation="true"></iron-a11y-keys>

            <form is="iron-form" method="get" action="/ajax/group/comment.php" id="commentForm">
                <input is="iron-input" type="text" name="comment" placeholder="Kommenter..." value="{{commentInput::input}}" class="comment_input" id="currentComment">
                <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="{{postId}}">
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: "post-comments",
            properties: {
                postId: {
                    type: Number
                },
                commentInput: {
                    type: String,
                    notify: true
                },
                target: {
                    type: Object,
                    value: function() {
                        return this.$.currentComment;
                    }
                }
            },
            listeners: {
                'iron-form-response': 'displayMessage'
            },
            sendComment: function(e) {
                    this.$.commentForm.submit();

            },
            displayMessage: function(e) {
                //Display response

            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by adding a setInterval to the sendComment function.